# Ubuntu Kernel problem

Tags: boot, grub2, kernel

I'm having troubles to boot my fresh Ubuntu 16 installation.
Installed kernels:

- 4.4.0.24-generic
- 4.4.0.22-generic
- 4.4.0.21-generic

Here are the results when booting from any of these kernels:

- Boot from "Ubuntu" -> keyboard not working (so I can't enter the boot password in LUKS)
- Boot from 4.4.0-24-generic -> all I'm getting here is "`Loading Linux 4.4.0-24-generic ... Loading initial ramdisk ...`", but the system will not boot
- Boot from 4.4.0.22-geneirc -> blank screen
- Boot from 4.4.0.21-generic -> works

I've tried to re-install Ubuntu 16.04 approximately 10 times, but I'm always getting the same results. Also, I had no issues with Ubuntu 14

Any idea what could be wrong?

- I'm using nvidia-364
- Secure boot has been disabled
- I've bought a new SSD for 300 USD, but the problem still exists

Comment: If you have preinstalled nvidia proprietary drivers, then I think you need to purge and reeinstall the driver with each kernel update. So try removing nvidia driver, then update and after you login with new kernel, reinstall the driver.

Comment: How did you install Nvidia drivers?

Comment: IIt always happens to me when I install proprietary gpu drivers and then upgrade to the new kernel. Have you tried to purge remove nvidia drivers and reboot again? How did you get the new kernels? Did you installed them manually or by using system update?

Comment: I've booted `kernel 4.4.0.21`, run `apt-get remove --purge nvidia*`, rebooted to `kernel 4.4.0.24` (which worked), installed `nvidia-367` via `software & updates` -> `additional drivers`, and rebooted again. Result: blankscreen :-(

@bensen: I've only used the software update to install kernel (an other) updates

Comment: not a solution comment but trying to understand your aim. what is your intention to install nvidia drivers on kernel 0.24? Isn't it possible to work without those drivers? I do not have a specific knowledge about what is going on while installing nvidia drivers, however **afaik**, it is being compiled with the current kernel headers you've installed on your system. This is may be directly related to those specific kernel versions or some 3rd party applications installed on the system. Can you drop to shell by using **ctrl+alt+f1/f2/f3** combination when blank screen appears?

Comment: @bensen: The system is slow as hell and the CPU usage is between 20%-50% (while doing nothing). `top` tells me that compiz is using all CPU resources, so I've been told that I should install  the nvidia driver since otherwise the GPU is not being used and the CPU will do all the rendering etc (and hence the computer is slow). However, when installing the nvidia driver, the screen is always black after reboot. So it looks like I have to choose between a slow PC and a blank screen.... :(